# Is it possible to override this function/class in a child theme?

Tags: functions, child-theme, pluggable, parent-theme

Is it possible to override this `widget` function from a parent theme? I saw this blog, but it dealt with a simpler case.

http://venutip.com/content/right-way-override-theme-functions

#### parent

```
class Chocolat_Widget_New_Entrys extends WP_Widget {

  function __construct() {...

  function widget( $args, $instance ) {...
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function( '', 'return register_widget( "Chocolat_Widget_New_Entrys" );' ) );
```

I attempted to use `remove_action('widgets_init','???');` but soon realized I could not get a handle on the function that registered it!

I thought about overriding the function and creating a subclass, but still, it is registered in the parent by the name of the parent class.

I thought about just copying the whole class, but child `functions.php` is [loaded before](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#Using_functions.php) `parents.php`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply need to run your code on a higher priority than what the parent theme is, the default on `add_action` function is 10 so you can use:

```
function s157343_unregister_widgets() {
     unregister_widget( 'Chocolat_Widget_New_Entrys' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 's157343_unregister_widgets', 20 );
```

This will unregister that widget. Of course, you can still create a new class that extends that widget's class to override the methods you want and register a new widget based on that:

```
class my_Chocolat_Widget_New_Entrys extends Chocolat_Widget_New_Entrys() {
    public function __construct() {}
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {}
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function( '', 'return register_widget( "my_Chocolat_Widget_New_Entrys" );' ) );
```

Comment: Wow I didn't know about default priorities! Are you sure you don't mean a lower priority? Wouldn't you want the parent to register first, so you can unregister it? If it was higher priority, wouldn't it run first, before the parent gets a chance to register?

Comment: I got so far as to create a subclass `class Child_Chocolat_Widget_New_Entrys extends Chocolat_Widget_New_Entrys {...`, but it is giving me errors: `Class 'Chocolat_Widget_New_Entrys' not found`. I added `require_once` to import the parent theme, but then it complains `Cannot redeclare chocolat_content_width()`. So how can I subclass this in the child theme, if the child file is loaded first?

Comment: Ok I was able to create a subclass by putting it in a separate file and requiring the separate file containing the subclass right before registering it. `add_action( 'widgets_init', function() {
  require 'child_chocolat_widget.php';
  return register_widget( "Child_Chocolat_Widget_New_Entrys" );
} );`

Answer (score 0):

So here is the clear example :

In functions.php :

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', function() { 
    require 'child_chocolat_widget.php'; 
    return register_widget(  "Child_Chocolat_Widget_New_Entrys" ); 
} );
```

In child_chocolat_widget.php  [Custom class file, whatever name you can keep ]

```
class my_Chocolat_Widget_New_Entrys extends Chocolat_Widget_New_Entrys() {
    public function __construct() {}
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) { //override method
     }
}
```