# Modify Plugin PHP Class in Child Theme - Correct Method

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, shortcode

This is the PHP class from the plugin

```
class WordPress_Shortcode {

    function wp_shortcode( $atts ) {

    }

}
```

I want to modify the plugin functionality via a child theme.

Edit. This relates to a PHP class which isn't a widget and doesn't extend WP_Widget so any answer using widgets_init will not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to override this function/class in a child theme?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/157343/is-it-possible-to-override-this-function-class-in-a-child-theme)

Comment: See edit. The solution you linked to works for a widget.

Comment: you need to unregister the existing shortcode with https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_shortcode/ and then redefine it to use you custom class.

Comment: No because the shortcode functionality is over ridden by the modified functions in the new class.